Use Link verification method when creating Cognito users with AdminCreateUser
My app is using AdminCreateUser to register new users, which then sends them the Invitation message via email (which asks them to copy a temporary password and log in with it).
I saw that the Verification message has an option to choose either Code or Link emails.
It would be a much better user experience for users to receive a Link on registration than to have to copy paste a password. Is it possible to send a Link type email to verify email after AdminCreateUser instead?

Could this be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268905/using-dynamic-placeholders-in-cognito-admincreateuser-email
